# Clarifications on docker's basic concepts

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm a bit lost with some of the basic concepts. It seems like the documentation / getting started requirements are basic knowledge about docker world that I don't have yet.

> A swarm is a cluster of Docker engines, or nodes, where you deploy
>   services. The Docker Engine CLI and API include commands to manage
>   swarm nodes (e.g., add or remove nodes), and deploy and orchestrate
>   services across the swarm.

1. I understand that a cluster is a group of physical/virtual computers behaving as one. **What is a cluster in the context of docker?**
2. Docker engine is what creating the docker daemon + rest api + provide CLI in the machine docker is installed. **What are docker engines**?
3. What is a node?
4. What is a docker node?
5. what is a swarm node?
6. what is a orchestrate service?
7. Finally, what is a swarm?

**I'm not looking for an article for each concept, only the minimal explanation that will help understand each concept in a overall.** From there, I can easily continue on my own.

Please explain any additional concept which is more advance then the mentioned ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great [website](http://devdocs.io/docker~1.12/) which I believe will answer all your questions.

1. A cluster in Docker context is a group of hosts on which the Docker engine is installed
2. The Docker engine it is the main *client - server* application. More on this [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#the-docker-platform)
3. A node is a physical or a virtual machine
4. A node is a physical or a virtual machine running the Docker engine
5. A [swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/nodes/) node it is the same as 3 and 4, however, the difference is that SWARM will be running on it alongside the Docker engine.
6. An orchestration service is something that will take care of container creation and their dependencies. More [here](http://talkincloud.com/cloud-computing/docker-container-orchestration-what-you-need-know)
7. [Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) is a clustering and scheduling tool for Docker.

Also, to learn more just do a Google search for the topic that you are interested in and you will find lots of useful explanations as well as examples :)

Comment: Currect me if I'm wrong (and I am), the docker engine manage containers which are faster then virtual machines but the Docker engine also manage swarms which manage virtual machines (nodes) which install additional docker engine for creating containers? Why it is better from manage the containers directly from my machine which I installed docker?

Comment: @StavAlfi Docker swarm is part of Docker engine, in other words the node requires Docker engine in order to run Swarm. You could manage your containers on its own using the docker-compose, however, with Swarm you can spread the load across the swarm nodes, also offers the possibility for the containers to communicate between each other and the last thing that I find useful is when you want to upgrade a stack of containers, you could do rolling upgrades. More info here: https://blog.bugsnag.com/container-orchestration-with-docker-swarm-mode/

Comment: So swarm manage containers (docker containers) and one of it's feature is load balancing between containers? And if I choose to create my own containers with out any swarm, I won't get load balancer for free?

Comment: Load balancing not on the containers but on the nodes where docker swarm is running. Docker swarm isn't a must and definitely you could use other mechanisms to accomplish that, but swarm comes with Docker (so a freebie). You could also use tools such as kubernetes or rancher :) @StavAlfi